# signalr application notworking after hosted with iis

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, signalr

Hi I created a stand alone project using SignalR. Its working fine with visual studio 2012. I used dot net  frame work 4 for this. But after hosting the application in iis7.5(server 2008r2) the signalR part not working. It giving the error, When i saw the client side debugged i got this:

```
"GET http://ChatApplication/chat/negotiate?_=1381730636439 404 (Not Found)".
```

Please help me. How to host a signalR project in iis 7.5(server 2008).

Comment: can you post part of the code that calls the hub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 steps:

1.Update the Signalr Application's Web.config File

2.Update the Web Page that Uses SignalR

3.Set up Windows Server 2008r2 and IIS 7.5

Check below mentioned link for more info.It has explained steps for how to do that.

[Hosting a SignalR application on Windows 2008r2 and IIS 7.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timlee/archive/2013/03/21/hosting-a-signalr-application-on-windows-2008r2-and-iis-7-5.aspx)

**UPDATE**

According to the OP's feedback you can fix this by installing below mentioned Update for IIS.

[A update is available that enables certain IIS 7.0 or IIS 7.5 handlers to handle requests whose URLs do not end with a period](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368)

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: I did the changes that was told in that link. But its not working same problem.

Comment: @user2586626 I only fixed this issue installing this hotfix http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368 of IIS 7.5